# mod_wgi installation failed with python3

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, python-3.5

trying to install mod_wsgi for django1.9 (python version 3.5 ) . But getting below error

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_validate.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_thread.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_stream.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_server.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_restrict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_metrics.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_memory.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_logger.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_interp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_daemon.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_buckets.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/wsgi_apache.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/server/mod_wsgi.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -L/home/webdev01/python3/lib -L/home/webdev01/python3/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m -lpython3.5m
    /usr/bin/ld: /home/webdev01/python3/lib/libpython3.5m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/webdev01/python3/lib/libpython3.5m.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/web0/home/webdev01/pythonenv3/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-6atgj_5e-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bcnhqmnp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /web0/home/webdev01/pythonenv3/include/site/python3.5/mod-wsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-6atgj_5e-build/
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation of:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#mixing-32-bit-and-64-bit-packages

You need to install Python with a shared library.